# How do you fill empty spaces in a UV with the existing textures?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, texture-painting

I've recently been making meshes for Roblox, but my latest one (an apple,) has these black seams, and I believe it's because of the empty black space in the UV. I saw a video a while back where I remember the person in the video clicking this button and it sort of stretched the already-drawn textures to touch each other and fill in the gaps. If this makes any sense, does anybody know how this YouTuber did it? Thanks!

Comment: maybe in the UV Editor > header menu > UV > Pack Islands?

Comment: @moonboots Thanks for the recommendation! I actually found the answer, all I needed was padding (you can see what I did to get padding in my answer,) which allowed me to sort of extend the texture to fill most of the empty parts of the image. Thanks! :)

Comment: ok, interesting

Answer (score 1):

I found out what it was!

All I needed for the texture to be fixed was padding.I got TexTools (a free plugin for Blender, found here: https://github.com/SavMartin/TexTools-Blender/releases/tag/v1.4.3) and added it to Blender. I then went to UV, selected the resolution (in this case I used 2048), and used the "Padding" slider to change the padding on the image. There's different values of padding for different resolutions, 16 being the recommended value for 2048, but I ended up doing a higher value for this particular mesh in order to fix the issue.

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this by default in Blender, but I'd still recommend getting TexTools anyway, it's a great addon! Thanks for reading, hopefully this helped if you had the same issue! :)